# ItemTouchHelper without swiping the view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am using the below code to swipe the recycler view items -

```
 ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.UP) {
       @Override
       public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
           return false;
       }

       @Override
       public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

           int pos = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

           if(recyclerAdapter!=null)
           {
               recyclerAdapter.goToDetailOnSwipe(pos);
           }
       }

   };
```

It works fine, but I do not want the recycler view item layout to be swiped up. I just want the onSwiped method to be called. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did a little research and found the solution. If you want to implement the swipe feature without redrawing the view , just override 'onChildDraw' method and do NOT call super.